# If option is selected in one multiselect, set it to disabled in another dropdown

Tags: jquery, select, each, multi-select

What is wrong with this code?  I have a multiselect (VendorIDs) and a select (vendorDropDown).  I want to set all the selected items in VendorIDs to disabled in vendorDropDown.  This doesn't work:

```
            $('#Vendor_IDs :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
                var v = $(selected).val();
                $("#vendorDropDown option[value='" + v + "']").attr("disabled", true);
            });
```

But, this does:

```
            $('#Vendor_IDs :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
                var v = $(selected).val();
                alert(v);
                $("#vendorDropDown option[value='" + v + "']").attr("disabled", true);
            });
```

How does adding the alert change anything?

Comment: Seems to work for me on http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/LAbrY/.  Where do you have the script?  Is it in a `$(function(){})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `var v = $(selected).val();` takes too long to execute for the next line to be on time. Try this:

```
 $('#Vendor_IDs :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
     $("#vendorDropDown option[value='" + $(selected).val() + "']").attr("disabled", true);
 });
```

This way, the second line is not dependent on the first line that was taking too long to execute. Let me know if it works.

-edited, 2nd try!-

```
 $('#Vendor_IDs :selected').each(function() {
     $("#vendorDropDown option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").attr("disabled", true);
 });
```

Comment: I had it that way before, but added the extra line to diagnose.  I think your answer has lead me to the problem though.  I think that the dropdown population probably hasn't finished executing...

Comment: Hm strange. Try using .each(function() { $('#vendor opt'+ $(this).val();} instead of .each(function(i, selected). Keep us posted. -edit- edited my answer

Comment: That was it.  Put my code within the .post that populates the dropdown and now all is well.